# How to write Firestore Rule to allow admin access

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to allow user to access their userID document and its sub collections or documents

at path:
/main-collection/{userid}

and I want that 'admin-userid' has reading permissions to all /main-collection documents and sub collections

/main-collection/{userid} as document

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {   

    match /main-collection/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId || request.auth.uid == 'admin-userid';

      match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId || request.auth.uid == 'admin-userid';
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user and the admin user need the same permissions to everything in the collection and the documents' subcollections:

```
match /main-collection/{userId} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId || request.auth.uid == 'admin-userid';
}

match /main-collection/{userId}/{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId || request.auth.uid == 'admin-userid';
}
```

Comment: so how you will get the variable {userId} here

Comment: Edited.  Try un-nesting the rules.